# Calling helper method from an admin view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
```

I inherited an application, architected to have both admin and non-admin sections. So, I have:

```
app/views/admin/....
app/views/....
app/helpers/admin/...
app/helpers/....
```

I am not sure how to call helper methods from the views. Let's take an example:

In app/helpers/admin/users_helper.rb, if I have:

```
def compute_total qty, price, commission
  (qty * price) + commission
end
```

and in app/helpers/users_helper.rb, if I have:

```
def compute_total qty, price
  qty * price
end
```

I have two questions:

1. Does Rails understand which method to call, based on the location of the view the method is called from?
2. What I want to force call a non-admin helper, from an admin view, or a helper from an admin view? How is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View helper methods you write on rails are available to all views and are mixed together (starting from Rails 4). Whenever there is a duplicate in name, rails will handle this by choosing the latter method alphabetically. For example,

```
module CustomHelper
  def compute_total qty, price, commission
  ......
end

module KustomHelper
  def compute_total qty, price
  ......
end
```

In the example above, the one that WILL always be called is the one from KustomHelper.

For your second question, what I would suggest is just use one method, that can handle both scenarios, such as this:

```
def compute_total(qty, price, commission = 0)
  (qty * price) + commission
end
```

You can declare the method anywhere and call it anywhere, no worries.

Good reference: https://mixandgo.com/blog/the-beginners-guide-to-rails-helpers

UPDATE:

I did not see that the OP uses version below 4, so the solution for OP's particular problem:

```
 # lib/custom_lib.rb
 class CustomLib
   def compute_total(qty, price, commission = 0)
     qty * price) + commission
   end
 end
```

Then call it from the view as such:

```
 <%= CustomLib.new.compute_total(qty, price) %>
```

Comment: Please note that this application uses Rails 3.2, not 4.

Comment: sorry did not see the rails version, my suggestion to you is to use lib class to encapsulate this method instead of using helper file

Comment: I'm aware I can create a library. What I am dealing with, is existing code, where the previous developer left admin helpers and non-admin helpers. I was trying to understand how scope is resolved.